# over labeling and zooming issue mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

1. I created custom mapbox using the dataset of building but it is having issue in some buildings
   [not proper rendering like lines in building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swH7X.jpg)
2. there is a labeling issue when the orientation is changed of the map
   it should it only provide the labels of front building not the labels behind it too
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utwrM.jpg)

any suggestions to overcome this problem

Comment: later I figured out to overcome these problems,  1. eject the building component and put the building street dataset v8 then add your building with condition then put the same height as the height of the building of the attribute , if they are same there won't be the rendering issue, 2. put the building layer in more priority than labelling and increase the opacity to 1

Answer (score 0):

later I figured out to overcome these problems, 1. eject the building component and put the building street dataset v8 then add your building with condition then put the same height as the height of the building of the attribute , if they are same there won't be the rendering issue, 2. put the building layer in more priority than labelling and increase the opacity to 1 –